# Junit Spring initialization is not working

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

When I run the below test, It just hangs. I took a thread dump and fount out that its blocking in SpringJunit4ClassRunner line 91 where there is this line

```
private static final Log logger = 
LogFactory.getLog(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class);

=========My Test Program ==============================
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/context-test.xml"})
public class ClassTest{

//    @Autowired
//    ClassName bean;

@Test
public void testConfig() {
    System.out.println("hello");
    //       System.out.println(bean.getConnectTimeout());
    System.out.println("end");
}

}
```

Is anyone facing the same problem and how did you fix this?

Comment: so what is the output of the above test?

Comment: There is no output. It just hangs.

Comment: Using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner without a context configuration I would have expected Spring to throw an exception. Are you sure you removed all the breakpoints? Have you tried using @RunWith(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class) just to make sure this is a Spring issue at all?

Comment: I have removed all the break points. I am not seeing any kind of error. The tests just hang. I ran it with BlockJunit4ClassRunner.class and it did seems to work fine.  That makes me curious what kind of spring issue is this.

Comment: I am sure that SpringJunit4ClassRunner is not able to instantiate Logger.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that JMockito was sharing the commons-logging library which the spring-context uses and jMockito was not initializing it which in turn caused this program to hang.

Removing the Jmockito dependency made it work.